# how to find only numbers in a array by using regexp in php?

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, preg-match-all

i am using `$front->getRequest()->getParams()` to get the url params. They look like this

```
Zend_Debug::dump($front->getRequest()->getParams());

array(4) {
  ["id"] => string(7) "3532231"
  ["module"] => string(7) "test"
  ["controller"] => string(6) "index"
  ["action"] => string(5) "index"
}
```

i am interested in running this through `preg_match_all` to get back only the id numbers by using some regexp similar to `([\s0-9])+`

for some reason i cant isolate that number.

There is the possibility that there will be more `id` like values in the array, but the `preg_match_all` should give them back to me in a new array

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_filter()](https://www.php.net/array_filter) is the way to go here.

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($value) {
    return preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/',$value);
});
```

You might also want to replace the preg_match() with is_numeric() for performance.

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($value) {
    return is_numeric($value);
});
```

That should give the same results.

Comment: The closure doesnt make sense in the is_numeric example: just use `array_filter($array, "is_numeric")`.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you capture the array and just access the element you want?

```
$params = $front->getRequest()->getParams();
echo $params['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *can* use regex, but a non-regex filter will be more efficient.

**DON'T** iterate `preg_match()` for each and every element in the array!

`is_numeric` is **VERY** forgiving and may be untrustworthy from case to case.

If you know you want to access the `id` elements value, just access it directly.

Methods: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27ff5b4839f8e205386325d1a26f1f0a687c15fa))

```
$array=["id"=>"3532231","module"=>"test","controller"=>"index","action"=>"index"];

var_export(preg_grep('/^\d+$/',$array));  // use regex to check if value is fully comprised of digits
// but regex should be avoided when a non-regex method is concise and accurate
echo "\n\n";

var_export(array_filter($array,'ctype_digit'));  // ctype_digit strictly checks the string for digits-only
//  calling is_numeric() may or may not be too forgiving for your case or future readers' cases

echo "\n\n";

echo $array['id']; // this is the most logical thing to do
```

Output:

```
array (
  'id' => '3532231',
)

array (
  'id' => '3532231',
)

3532231
```