# How to do divide an array into two as int and string arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array and I want to divide this array into two as string and integer arrays. Is that possible?

Array:

```
[
    0 => "4"
    1 => "8"
    2 => "15"
    3 => "16"
    4 => "23"
    5 => "42"
    6 => "apple"
    7 => "water"
]
```

Integer array:

```
[
    0 => "4"
    1 => "8"
    2 => "15"
    3 => "16"
    4 => "23"
    5 => "42"
]
```

String array:

```
[
    0 => "apple"
    1 => "water"
]
```

Comment: I tried but I cant figure out.. I couldn't any docs about it or any example. (except php.net, but that was so complicated)

Comment: `$numerics = array_filter($data, 'is_numeric');
$nonNumerics = array_diff($data, $numerics);`

Comment: OP posted no coding attempt what-so-ever (using SO as a free coding service).  Downvote.  Additional duplicates: for anyone who can list multiple duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16802383/how-to-save-numbers-only-from-an-array-into-a-new-array
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857589/how-to-find-only-numbers-in-a-array-by-using-regexp-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$ints = array_filter($arr, 'is_numeric');
$strs = array_filter($arr, function($v){ return !is_numeric($v); });
```

*You can call [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on `$ints` and `$strs` if you need to reset the keys so they start from zero.* See it in action: https://eval.in/907987.

---

Or you can make your own loop and store it in separate arrays:

```
$ints = array();
$strs = array();
foreach($arr as $v){
    if(is_numeric($v)){
        $ints[] = $v;
    }else{
        $strs[] = $v;
    }
}
```

Check it out [here](https://eval.in/907980) and see the output:

**ints**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 16
    [4] => 23
    [5] => 42
)
```

**strs**

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple
    [1] => water
)
```